# Get Nginx work with updated openssl

Tags: nginx, openssl

I upgrade openssl to 1.0.0 from 0.9.8 on a Linux Ubuntu server. It is installed in /usr/local/ssl. Nginx was compiled with openssl 0.9.8. How to get Nginx to link to the updated version of openssl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either recompile nginx, passing the --with-openssl=/usr/local/ssl option to configure, or you can use LD_LIBRARY_PATH when starting nginx, doing something like "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/ssl:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/sbin/nginx" .